# No Nvidia Drivers?! <Nvidia>

Tags: drivers, nvidia, additional-drivers

So after re-installing Ubuntu multiple times, I still have not gotten my Nvidia drivers to appear. I've  tried manually installing them, and everything else in the book, but when opening my additional drivers(In Virtual Box) all I get is a virtual box virtual graphics driver, which I can not use for my needs.

Comment: If you're running Ubuntu within Virtualbox, it does not have direct access to your video card and will not (and cannot) use Nvidia drivers. (It is running in a *virtual machine*, after all, not a real one.) If you actually install Ubuntu to your computer (not within a virtual machine), the Nvidia drivers should be an option. But right now everything is being piped though Virtualbox and your host OS's graphics card drivers, so an Nvidia driver in the Ubuntu guest OS is irrelevant (wouldn't help). (If you're trying to do video card passthrough, the situation may be a bit different)

Comment: What do you recommend I do for this?

Comment: You can just use the default Virtualbox graphics driver, since that's the  one that will work best when running Ubuntu within Virtualbox. However, if you want to give Ubuntu direct access to your video card, you can actually install Ubuntu directly onto your computer (i.e. not in a virtual machine). If things are working ok, leave it be and don't worry about it.